# Promise then callback context "this.callFunc() is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to hide or show a React-native *dialog* upon button click but I don't know why my code generates the following error:

```
> this.callFunc() is not a function.
```

The instruction is executed within a *fetch.then* callback.

I use `dialogVisible` variable as a flag to know whether the dialog should be hiden or shown.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ConfirmDialog } from 'react-native-simple-dialogs';
export default class RegistrationScreen extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dialogVisible: false,
        };
        this.callFunc = this.callFunc.bind(this);
    }

    callFunc = () =>
    {
        if (this.state.dialogVisible) {
            this.setState({ dialogVisible: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({ dialogVisible: true });
        }
    };

    getRegData()
    {
        fetch('http://test/api/registration/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + token,
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                this.callFunc(); // getting error here
            } else if (response.status === 200) {
                response
                    .json()
                    .then(function (object)
                    {

                    })
                    .catch(error =>
                    {
                        Alert.alert(error.message);
                    });
            }
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        let { voucherCode } = this.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text onPress={this.getRegData}>
                    click me
                </Text>
                <ConfirmDialog
                    visible={this.state.dialogVisible}
                    title="Error"
                    onTouchOutside={() => this.setState({ dialogVisible: false })}
                    positiveButton={{
                        title: 'OK',
                        onPress: () => alert('Ok touched!'),
                    }}>
                    <View>
                        <Image
                            style={{ height: 40, width: 40, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                            source={images.success_alert}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ConfirmDialog>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the callback inside `getRegData()` method, which isn't bound to the component instance. Either bind it the same way as `this.callFunc` or use arrow function form: `getRegData = () => {`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm doing same what you said, but getting same error can you please change in my above code and reply.

Comment: Also try using arrow function for your callback: `then((response) =>  {`

Comment: Not working! can you please change in my above code and reply